# Managing firebase instances in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm cleaning up a flutter app and learning to use the dart profiler.

In my initial analysis I noted that the developers have created FirebaseAuth.instace almost everywhere in the app wherever data is streamed or fetched. Does this affect the app/memory/performance in any tangible way?

Also, isn't it better to create a single instance of FirebaseAuth or others like Firestore and use provider/riverpod/bloc to pass that instance rather than invoke it everywhere individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this affect the app/memory/performance in any tangible way?

No.

> Also, isn't it better to create a single instance of FirebaseAuth or others like Firestore and use provider/riverpod/bloc to pass that instance rather than invoke it everywhere individually?

No.  Each returned instance is a singleton.  There is only one actual instance per initialized app returned every time you call it.

It just doesn't matter much whether you "invoke" the instance or use a stored object from the call.  Do whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, what about setting up multiple streams listening to multiple documents? Is it the same?

Comment: If you have another question, please post it separately with the code that you're unclear about.